# Access to users address in Metamask

Tags: metamask, addresses, privacy, gui

I am building a Web dApp and would like to show the users address. Is it possible read this from the `signer` object I get from MetaMask? Or is this intentionally not possible?

If it is not possible, what are common ways to achieve this goal? Ask the user explicitly? (This seems a bit cumbersome to me from a UI perspective but I can see how it is much better from the privacy perspective)

Thanks!

Edit: Clarify where the problem was for me.

Comment: Do you want the user's wallet address, their native asset balance (e.g. ETH), or an ERC-20 token balance? Please clarify your question.

Comment: As per your clarification, this question is a duplicate. There are many other posts for looking up an ERC-20 token balance. Check them out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using ethers.js in that case you can get the address from the signer object. Try:

```
signer.getAddress()
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me, I have no idea why you received -1.

Comment: I guess people can be cruel, glad to hear it worked for you!

Comment: trizin, this answer is exactly what I need. Thank you!